# App background process is running fine in ios simulator But when i check in real device app Background is not running

Tags: ios

In my AppDelegate I have:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

      UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(2)

     return true

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {  
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

In my `viewDidload` I have

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 40, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.printBackground

 ), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

now in my view controller I have a function

```
func printBackground(){

   print ("Background is woring")

}
```

Its working fine on iOS simulator, but when I run this on a real device, the Background process is not working.

Comment: You cannot run timers in the background like that.  Applications running under Xcode have unlimited background time, but this is not the case when apps are run normally.

Comment: So which process I should follow??

Comment: You can refer to background programming in the iOS Application Programming Guide, but there are limited background execution modes available.